# tomcat jsvc launch error on Mac OS snow leopard

Tags: macos, tomcat, osx-snow-leopard, tomcat6, jsvc

I've a problem with a tomcat 6 installation in daemon mode on Mac OS 10.6.8 (32bit)

I've followed this tutorial: http://www.malisphoto.com/tips/tomcatonosx.html

Tomcat works with a manual startup (startup.sh) But when try to launch my Tomcat5.sh file tomcat don't start

My catalina.out file say:

```
fatal error: mach_msg (send) failed: 0x10000003

Service killed by signal 5
```

It seems to be a 64bit problem but the file command on my jsvc say everything is ok

```
$ file jsvc
jsvc: Mach-O executable i386
```

I've try the same config (as I think) on an other mac with Lion (10.7.2) and everything works correctly.

Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Googling the error "mach_msg (send) failed..." turns up this:
https://github.com/neo4j-attic/yajsw/issues/1 which suggests this could be permissions-related.

What I would do is instead of the tutorial you mentioned, install Tomcat via Homebrew.
Steps:

- Install Homebrew: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"`
  (see [Homebrew installation instructions](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation))
- Install Tomcat: `brew install tomcat`

And done! Now you can just run startup.sh and shutdown.sh to start/stop Tomcat, which shouldn't give you any problems.